# google map marker updating with sql database

Tags: javascript, google-maps

I'm new to Google map. I try to develop tracking system using Google map. I successfully develop a map connecting to a sql database to retrieve the markers. the database updating according to the gps units. I want to show it in the map once a 10 seconds. this is my cord. If anybody can, please kindly help me. thanks.

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8"/>
<title>Google Maps AJAX + mySQL/PHP Example</title>
 <script src="http://maps.google.com/maps/api/js?sensor=false"
        type="text/javascript"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">
 //<![CDATA[

  var customIcons = {
  restaurant: {
    icon: 'http://labs.google.com/ridefinder/images/mm_20_blue.png',
    shadow: 'http://labs.google.com/ridefinder/images/mm_20_shadow.png'
  },
  bar: {
    icon: 'http://labs.google.com/ridefinder/images/mm_20_red.png',
    shadow: 'http://labs.google.com/ridefinder/images/mm_20_shadow.png'
  }
  };


function load() {
  var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map"), {
    center: new google.maps.LatLng(6.93360361159907, 79.85547582),
    zoom: 13,
    mapTypeId: 'roadmap'
  });
  var infoWindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow;

  // Change this depending on the name of your PHP file
  downloadUrl("phpsqlajax_genxml.php", function(data) {
    var xml = data.responseXML;
    var markers = xml.documentElement.getElementsByTagName("marker");
    for (var i = 0; i < markers.length; i++) {
      var name = markers[i].getAttribute("name");
      var address = markers[i].getAttribute("address");
      var type = markers[i].getAttribute("type");
      var point = new google.maps.LatLng(
          parseFloat(markers[i].getAttribute("lat")),
          parseFloat(markers[i].getAttribute("lng")));
      var html = "<b>" + name + "</b> <br/>" + address;
      var icon = customIcons[type] || {};
      var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
        map: map,
        position: point,
        icon: icon.icon,
        shadow: icon.shadow
      });
      bindInfoWindow(marker, map, infoWindow, html);
    }
  });
}

function bindInfoWindow(marker, map, infoWindow, html) {
  google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function() {
    infoWindow.setContent(html);
    infoWindow.open(map, marker);
  });
}

function doNothing() {}

//]]>
</script>


</head>

 <body onload="load()">
 <div id="map" style="width: 1000px; height: 600px"></div>
 </body>
 </html>
```

Answer (score 1):

If you are planning on updating the marker on the map every 10 seconds, you will have to request the position data from the db every 10 seconds. For a small scale project, [polling](http://techoctave.com/c7/posts/60-simple-long-polling-example-with-javascript-and-jquery) the db would be the easiest option. Otherwise, you can look at [web sockets](http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/javascript-ajax/start-using-html5-websockets-today/).

Inside the callback, you can change the marker position with

```
marker.setPosition()
```